# Whats the most concise way to pick a random element by weight in c#?

Tags: c#, linq, weighted, weighted-average

Lets assume:

`List<element>` which element is:

```
public class Element {
   int Weight { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to achieve is, select an element randomly by the weight.
For example:

```
Element_1.Weight = 100;
Element_2.Weight = 50;
Element_3.Weight = 200;
```

So

- the chance `Element_1` got selected is 100/(100+50+200)=28.57%
- the chance `Element_2` got selected is 50/(100+50+200)=14.29%
- the chance `Element_3` got selected is 200/(100+50+200)=57.14%

I know I can create a loop, calculate total, etc...

*What I want to learn is, whats the best way to do this by Linq in ONE line (or as short as possible), thanks.*

**UPDATE**

I found my answer below. First thing I learn is: **Linq is NOT magic, it's slower then well-designed loop**.

So my question becomes find a random element by weight, (without as short as possible stuff :)

Comment: So you want short code, but you don't care about it being slow?

Comment: no no, I know loop is slow, so I want to use Linq, should be faster. Not very short, just not as complex as use loop and loop again. I can imaging what I can do is: 1: get total, 2: random from total 3: get item in the range.. quite complex and slow, I guess

Comment: Linq will be slower that loop based code. If you want fast code, you need to precompute in `O(n)` so you can a `O(1)` lookup. But the code for that will be relatively complex.

Comment: Where did you see "Linq will be slower that loop based code"? I thought linq is faster than that, and I use plenty of linq in my code :(

Comment: How do you think Linq(to objects) works? Magic? It just encapsulates the loop, and is typically slower by a factor of about 2-3 than hand written loops. The main advantage of linq is shorter clearer code.

Comment: LINQ is indeed slower than writing an efficent iterative algorithm yourself. The reason for linq is that it is much easier to read/use and far less likely to result in a bug.

Comment: #CodeInChaos I don't know. I know loop is the worst and stupid way. So linq might be better, or at least it can do some short circuits in the loop. Anyway, I don't think my skill on C# is good, so I would rather use linq which coded by professionals.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - 2 to 3 times slower is a gross exaggeration.

Comment: Does your array change between different runs? It is relatively simple to get `O(n)` precomputation with `O(log(n))` lookup. And how many elements are there in the collection? If it's only a handful, a linear search will still be fast.

Comment: @roken If the content of your delegates/lambdas is cheap, that factor should be correct. If the content of the lambdas is expensive, the difference obviously gets smaller.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Yes, it changes. It's a pick one from a `List` by weight function, `List` changes all the time. I think I will just use Linq to get total, then do random my self.

Comment: @CodeInChaos "If the content of the lambdas is expensive" how you decide? `String` is cheap? `Int` is cheap, `object/class` is expensive? is it?

Comment: "cheap" means "code which is executed in a short time". File operations and remote calculations, as well as complex algorithms are expensive, meaning "taking a lot of time".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a **generic version** (useful for using with a (singleton) randomize helper, consider whether you need a constant seed or not)

usage:

```
randomizer.GetRandomItem(items, x => x.Weight)
```

code:

```
public T GetRandomItem<T>(IEnumerable<T> itemsEnumerable, Func<T, int> weightKey)
{
    var items = itemsEnumerable.ToList();

    var totalWeight = items.Sum(x => weightKey(x));
    var randomWeightedIndex = _random.Next(totalWeight);
    var itemWeightedIndex = 0;
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        itemWeightedIndex += weightKey(item);
        if(randomWeightedIndex < itemWeightedIndex)
            return item;
    }
    throw new ArgumentException("Collection count and weights must be greater than 0");
}
```

Comment: I love this solution, looks very very decent. In addition, I will edit and allow `totalWeight=0`, then just random pick one (with equal chance since them weights are same) without throw an exception.

Comment: I think here I found an issue (a little issue), you should use `randomWeightedIndex = _random.Next(totalWeight)+1;`, then compare `if(randomWeightedIndex <= itemWeightedIndex)`. Otherwise the chance of been selected is slightly different of my requirement in my question.

Comment: I am rather sure it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: It makes. Lets assume `A=0, B=2`, the chance about A been selected is 0%, and B is 100%. `R=rand.Next(2)` will return 0-1. When R=1, A will be selected, Which becomes 50% for A and B. If use +1, R=1 to 2, neither will <=0

Comment: because the weight-key, in common sense, should >=0, so I use byte, from 0-255 are legal weight-key

Comment: At zero based indexes it makes a difference, but I consider weight value 0 as "0% chance", so ... it all depends on the definition. However it's nice to see you find it useful.

Answer (score 5):

```
// assuming rnd is an already instantiated instance of the Random class
var max = list.Sum(y => y.Weight);
var rand = rnd.Next(max);
var res = list
    .FirstOrDefault(x => rand >= (max -= x.Weight));
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a fast solution with precomputation. The precomputation takes `O(n)`, the search `O(log(n))`.

Precompute:

```
int[] lookup=new int[elements.Length];
lookup[0]=elements[0].Weight-1;
for(int i=1;i<lookup.Length;i++)
{
  lookup[i]=lookup[i-1]+elements[i].Weight;
}
```

To generate:

```
int total=lookup[lookup.Length-1];
int chosen=random.GetNext(total);
int index=Array.BinarySearch(lookup,chosen);
if(index<0)
  index=~index;
return elements[index];
```

---

But if the list changes between each search, you can instead use a simple `O(n)` linear search:

```
int total=elements.Sum(e=>e.Weight);
int chosen=random.GetNext(total);
int runningSum=0;
foreach(var element in elements)
{
  runningSum+=element.Weight;
  if(chosen<runningSum)
    return element;
}
```

Comment: Where's the LINQ from the question? ;)

Comment: `int total=elements.Sum(e=>e.Weight)` :P That's the only place where I found linq useful in this problem. I couldn't find a fast and clean way to perform the search itself with linq.

Answer (score 2):

This could work:

```
int weightsSum = list.Sum(element => element.Weight);
int start = 1;
var partitions = list.Select(element => 
                 { 
                   var oldStart = start;
                   start += element.Weight;
                   return new { Element = element, End = oldStart + element.Weight - 1};
                 });

var randomWeight = random.Next(weightsSum);
var randomElement = partitions.First(partition => (partition.End > randomWeight)).
                               Select(partition => partition.Element);
```

Basically, for each element a partition is created with an end weight.
In your example, Element1 would associated to (1-->100), Element2 associated to (101-->151) and so on...

Then a random weight sum is calculated and we look for the range which is associated to it.

You could also compute the sum in the method group but that would introduce another side effect...

Note that I'm not saying this is elegant or fast. But it does use linq (not in one line...)

Comment: thanks. I think I will leave linq except the sum part, since it creates too much new object on the way

Answer (score -1):

.Net 6 introduced .MaxBy making this much easier.

This could now be simplified to the following one-liner:

```
list.MaxBy(x => rng.GetNext(x.weight));
```

This works best if the weights are large or floating point numbers, otherwise there will be collisions, which can be prevented by multiplying the weight by some factor.

Comment: what's rng? please elaborate